# LINQ - Buidling a search query

Tags: linq

I am building up a search query for my customer search function:
I have all these fields passing into the function and wonder what is the best way to build up the LINQ expression. Some of the fields maybe an empty string and the search should be using "contains" instead of searching the exact field string

```
public List<Customer> SearchCustomer(
    string membershipID, 
    string preferName, 
    string firstName, 
    string lastName, 
    string nric, 
    string phoneNumber, 
    string email, 
    DateTime dob, 
    string gender, 
    string address, 
    Boolean vip, 
    bool isDeleted)
```

Comment: what is the query you want the perform? a minimal example is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage multiple filter parameters in the following way:

```
var result = customerCollection.
    .Where(c => membershipID != null ? c.membershipId.Contains(membershipID) : true)
    .Where(c => preferName != null ? c.preferName.Contains(membershipID) : true)

    ...

    .ToList();
```

I hope you get the idea

Comment: I have this and it is working fine only until I key in the membershipID and prefer name & first name. If I try to search more using other fields, it will return me 0 record.

List<Customer> customers = context.Customers.Where(x => membershipID != 0 ?x.MembershipID.ToString().Contains(membershipID.ToString()) : true)
.Where(x => preferName != null ? x.PreferName.Contains(preferName) : true)
.Where(x => firstName != null ? x.FirstName.Contains(firstName) : true)
.Where(x => lastName != null ? x.LastName.Contains(lastName) : true)

Comment: Post the entire query you are using